# como verificar preenchimento do <input type=date> em js?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou fazendo um formulário e queria que não fosse possível avançar se o campo date não tivessem sido preenchidos, porém não sei como passar os parâmetros para tal verificação, a verificação deve ser feita em JS.

```html
  <label for="nasc">Data de nascimento:</label>
        <input type="date" id="nasc" name="nasc" min= "1990-12-30"max="2001-12-30"  />
```

Comment: Você não quer permitir avançar no click de um **botão**?

Comment: Eu quero que quando a pessoa apertar em enviar e esse campo não tiver sido preenchido ainda deve aparecer uma alert dizendo que ouve um erro.

Comment: Tente executar o meu exemplo ou o de [LeAndrade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/75267/leandrade) e veja qual se adapta à sua necessidade. A diferença é a chamada do *JS* para a validação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
  
    function validarData(){
     var data = document.getElementById("nasc");
     if(data.value == ''){
      alert("Data não preenchida!");
      return;
     }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Da11a2 Exemplo</title>
   
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <label for="nasc">Data de nascimento:</label>
            <input type="date" id="nasc" name="nasc" min= "1990-12-30"max="2001-12-30"  />
            
            <button onClick="validarData()"> Enviar </button>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Você pode fazer essa validação ao clicar no botão desejado para enviar seu `form`, neste caso o **Botão Enviar**. 
Fiz um exemplo simples onde é feito uma validação se o campo não foi preenchido, neste caso um alerta é invocado.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Da11a2 Exemplo</title>

<script>

function validarData(){
    var data = document.getElementById("nasc");
    if(data.value == ''){
        alert("Data não preenchida!");
        return;
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<label for="nasc">Data de nascimento:</label>
        <input type="date" id="nasc" name="nasc" min= "1990-12-30"max="2001-12-30"  />

        <button onClick="validarData()"> Enviar </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Isso é bem simples, de uma maneira básica você pode pegar se o campo está vazio usando um `if` e tratar a mensagem a cada evento de **blur** no campo:

```js
let valor = document.getElementById('nasc');

valor.onblur = function() {
  if(valor.value == '') {
    valor.style.borderColor = 'red';
    alert('Preencha este campo!');
  } else {
    valor.style.borderColor = 'green';
    alert('OK! Campo preenchido.');
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="nasc">Data de nascimento:</label>
<input type="date" id="nasc" name="nasc" min="1990-12-30" max="2001-12-30" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução simples, restrito aos recursos nativos e apenas com javascript, é adicionar um evento no foco dos controles do form, adicionar a propriedade `required` no seu input de data de nascimento e utilizar o método `checkValidity()`.

```js
let inputNasc = document.getElementById("nasc");
let controles = document.getElementById("formulario").elements;

//método de validação
let validarNascimento = function() {
  if (this != inputNasc && !inputNasc.checkValidity()) {
    alert("Primeiro, informe a sua data de Nascimento");
    inputNasc.focus();
  }
}

//Bind dos eventos
for (let i = 0; i < controles.length; i++) {
  controles[i].onfocus = validarNascimento;
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario">
  <label for="nasc">Data de nascimento:</label>
  <input type="date" id="nasc" name="nasc" min="1990-12-30" max="2001-12-30" required />
  
  <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
  <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome">
</form>
```